# Line of Intersection between 2 Planes

Tags: math, equation, plane

I watched and tried to understand bunch of sites and videos about this, and I came into a weird conclusions and some questions. I need some help to explain which one of the method is right, or even both of them are right (but I got different result from each methods).

I'm sorry that I'm bad at explaining things, the first method is solve the equations normally. But, here the link for the video I tried to learn from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7CfCDkRwfY

Second method is to do cross product for the direction and find the point by set one of the variables as 0. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jozabh0lFmo

I tried for this example

> x+2y+z−1=0
>
> 2x+3y−2z+2=0

and turned out for different answers. Is both of the method are correct, or which one? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations with three unknowns.

You can eliminate one variable and solve for a relationship between the remaining two.  Let's eliminate z.

Multiply the first equation by 2:

```
2x + 4y + 2z = 2
```

Add this to the second equation:

```
4x + 7y = 0
```

You can solve for y as a function of x:

```
y = -4x/7
```

Substitute this back into the first equation:

```
x  - 8x/7 + z = 1
```

Simplify by combining the first and second terms:

```
-x/7 + z = 1
```

Solve for z:

```
z = 1 + x/7
```

Now you have an equation for the line in 3D space.

```
-inf <= x <= +inf
y = -4x/7
z = 1 + x/7
```

Both your equations are satisfied by these two points.  Since two points are enough to define a line in Euclidean space I'd say I've got the correct answer.

This line goes through the point `(0, 0, 1)`.  It also goes through `(7, -4, 2)`

Here's a parametric representation of that line for `-inf <= t <= +inf`:

```
(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 1) + t*(7, -4, 1)
```

You can see that when `t = 0 (x, y, z) = (0, 0, 1)` (first point above) and when `t = 1 (x, y, z) = (7, -4, 2)` (second point above).

I didn't look at either of your videos.  This is how I'd solve it.

This is high school algebra.